How to check the name of function in outer_middleware after invoking of a handler aiogram 3.7
I have middleware class of telegram bot system:
from typing import Any, Awaitable, Callable, Dict
import logging
import inspect
from pprint import pprint

from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import TelegramObject


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class LoggingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    async def __call__(
            self, handler: Callable[[TelegramObject, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
            event: TelegramObject,
            data: Dict[str, Any]
    ) -> Any:
        result = await handler(event, data)
        logger.debug(f"##THIS IS MOCK LOGGER: ")
        return result

I attach it to dispatcher as an outer_middleware.
I want to check which function has been invoked by result = await handler(event, data) and show it's name in logs.
I have tried to reveal that by inspect module, but i get a lot of non-understandable-by-myself information.

I have found a way out of it using flags.
In handlers i specify the name of function like:
@router.callback_query(F.data == "contacts", StateFilter(default_state), flags={'name': 'answer_contacts'})
async def answer_contacts(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
...

and then in router i extract flag and attach value of key name to logger:
async def logging_middleware(handler, event, data):
    flags_data = extract_flags(data)
    ...

and now i have found the solution:
async def logging_middleware(handler, event, data):
    decorated_func = str(data["handler"].callback).split(" ")[1]


and now i have found pretty and easy solution, which, i seem is the most right way:
async def logging_middleware(handler, event, data):
    decorated_func = str(data["handler"].callback).split(" ")[1]

